# Script to do a mirror copy

Tags: ms-dos

I have adapted a script to find "bookmarks." in the chrome profiles. but I have about 4 profiles.

Profile 1, Profile 2, Profile 3, Profile 4.

is there a way to create the found "bookmarks." to go into the destination copied profile location? so it matches the source?... currently it trys to overwrite the destination.

My script is as follows:

cd\Users\David\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\

for /r %%a in (bookmarks.*) do xcopy "%%a" c:\Users\David\Downloads\testme /s /i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Script to do a mirror copy**
>
> is there a way to create the found "bookmarks." to go into the
>   destination copied profile location? so it matches the source?

Sure you can do this with [**Robocopy**](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) assuming you're using a modern version of Windows.

*Look over options to ensure all is set for your needs. Ensure the `SRC` variable is set to the source location where to start the search to find bookmarks. to copy over, and that the `DEST` variable is the destination location where those files are to be copied to if they exist on the source location but not (or different) than what's on the destination location.*

```
SET SRC="C:\path\source"
SET DEST="C:\path\destination"
SET FName=bookmarks.*
SET LOG=C:\Path\Log.txt
::   If you do not want a log file, remove the "/LOG+:%LOG%" below
SET OPT=/PURGE /S /NP /R:5 /LOG+:%Log% /TS /FP
SET CMD=robocopy %SRC% %FName% %DEST% %OPT%
%CMD%
```

---

### Further Resources and Reading

- [**Robocopy**](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Answer (score 2):

Also, take a look at the `/MIR` parameter of RoboCopy. It mirrors the directory structure exactly in the destination.

Example:

```
robocopy "c:\users\johndoe\desktop\test" "d:\test" Bookmarks.* /mir
```

This copies files that're named Bookmarks (with any extension) recursively, maintaining the same directory structure in the destination. `/MIR` parameter takes care of that.

Comment: Ohhhhh!! I just couldn't work out the /MIR command with only spefic files.... you have pointed me in the correct direction